# how to determine if a main window of detached process is visible or not

Tags: qt, modal-dialog, shared-memory, qprocess, blocked

I have a tool to run main application - both are `QApplications`.
in the tool I start main app as `QProcess::startDetached("myapp.exe", QStringList() << "-arg1" << "-arg2", "C:/myFolder/");`

then the tool finishes its work and the main app is still working.

I can start the tool again, and send commands via `QSharedMemory`.
But if main app has opened modal dialog, it cannot handle new commands.

I need to determine from the tool that main app is busy with modal dialog and return some kind of error.

could anyone please tell me what is the simplest way to do it.

I have two ideas, but they really don't know if any of them will work:

1. use `QApplication::activeModalWidget()`, but how to get `QApplication*` of main app from the tool?
2. put information that the main app is busy in shared memory, and the tool'll check it before closing itself. - I'm not sure that the main app'll be able to save something in shared memory while it's busy with modal dialog.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'd use [QLocalServer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlocalserver.html) in the main app and [QLocalSocket](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlocalsocket.html) in the tool.

When the main app starts, it starts the local server running, allowing the tool to connect to it and communicate as required.

At its most basic level, if the tool can connect to the server, you know the main application is running. However I would recommend using this IPC mechanism over QSharedMemory.

Done properly, the tool can happily disconnect and reconnect without issue.

Qt provides an example of how to use [QLocalServer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/ipc-localfortuneserver.html) with [QLocalSocket](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/ipc-localfortuneclient.html)